# Handoff and Instant Hotspot with El Capitan on MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, macos, continuity

after upgrade to El Capitan, I don't get Instant Hotspot and Handoff to work (I am particularly interested in the possibility to make phone calls using my iPhone 5 from my Mac). It was working on Yosemite.

Now I saw on [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204689) that info about the compatibility:

> Handoff and Instant Hotspot
>
> Handoff and Instant Hotspot are supported by the following Mac models,
>   and require OS X Yosemite:
>
> ```
> MacBook Air (Mid 2012 and later)
> MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 and later)
> MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015)
> iMac (Late 2012 and later)
> Mac mini (Late 2012 and later)
> Mac Pro (Late 2013)
> ```

Now I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013) and it does not seem to be mentioned here.

My Question: can I use Handoff and Instant Hotspot with my MacBook Pro Retina?

Becauese I can't seem to be able to set it up (enabled in System Preferences -> General -> Allow Handoff is enabled) in FaceTime.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working, but your computer is included in "MacBook Pro (Mid 2012 and later)."

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off Bluetooth on your Mac
2. Delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
3. Turn Bluetooth back on